# Parse.com Android SDK equivalent to REST API's relatedTo

Tags: android, parse-platform

here is a snippet from the Parse documentation for the REST API, it's pretty much my use case:

> If you want to retrieve objects that are members of Relation field of a parent object, you can use the $relatedTo operator. Imagine you have a Post class and User class, where each Post can be liked by many users. If the Users that liked a Post were stored in a Relation on the post under the key "likes", you can find the users that liked a particular post by:

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MYAPPID" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MYRESTKEY" \
     -G \
     --data-urlencode 'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"8TOXdXf3tz"},"key":"likes"}}' \
     https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

however I couldn't find an android equivalent for this type of query.

If there really isn't anything like that, I'd probably:

1. Do the query myself using a REST client e.g. Volley/Retrofit
2. Query for the PostClass and have the UserClass included

With both options I'd lose the magic of ParseQueryAdapter and write a lot more code.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I assume you've looked that this: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational

Comment: mbm29414 yes, but it seems to be missing the equivalent of the REST query type mentioned above. Or it's just not obvious to me.